# Failing to start an app as service through systemd using userdata

Tags: linux, systemd

I want to start my app as service from systemd but the app is not starting.

My unit file appstart.service looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Application start

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ec2-user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /home/ec2-user/project/restartScript.sh
SyslogIdentifier=App_start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

RestartScript.sh should start the java app:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE="tst,development"
cd /home/ec2-user/project
pkill java
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/ec2-user/project/app.jar >>/home/ec2-user/project/web.log 2>>/home/ec2-user/project/web-error.log &
```

I am starting the app as a service this way using User Data on AWS EC2 instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /home/ec2-user/project
cd /home/ec2-user/project
sudo wget -P /home/ec2-user/project/ https://tst.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/app.jar
chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/project
sudo wget -P /home/ec2-user/project/ https://tst.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/restartScript.sh
sudo chmod 755 /home/ec2-user/project/restartScript.sh
cd /etc/systemd/system/
sudo wget /etc/systemd/system/ https://tst.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/appstart.service
sudo su 
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable appstart.service
systemctl start appstart.service
exit
```

The output I am getting when I start the EC2 instance this way is:

```
$ systemctl status appstart.service
● appstart.service - Application start
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/appstart.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2022-08-25 13:35:52 UTC; 4min 19s ago
  Process: 7328 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /home/ec2-user/project/restartScript.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7328 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 25 13:35:52 ip-x-x-x-x.tst.local systemd[1]: Started Application start.
```

When I try to do
systemctl start appstart.service
Nothing changes. The application is not working.

Any idea why is this happening?

OS on the machine:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
```

Comment: Can you successfully run `RestartScript.sh` script? if yes What is it's output?

Comment: When I start the script manually, it starts the app. So, manually, the script runs but through appstart.service it does not.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong, even the `status` shows success on execution `Main PID: 7328 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)` Can you share the `java` code you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong with this, the service is running and the application runs and finishes successfully. The `Active` state of the service becomes `inactive (dead)` in case of failure it should be `Failed` and `Main PID` is `(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`.

To verify that the service is running correct, write this line somewhere in `RestartScript.sh`:

`echo "Test" > test.txt`

After starting the service you will find the created file near `RestartScript.sh` file.

Comment: I have added echo "Test" > test.txt into the script but I don't have test.txt file in /home/ec2-user/project folder. It seems like it is not running the script at all. Any idea why?

Comment: That's weird!!! Can you remove everything else in the script file and just leave the `echo` command? And let me know if it creats the file.

Comment: I have one last thing to try, remove `cd` from you script, and in your `[Service]` section add `WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/project` Can you try it now?

Comment: I tried that as well and now I get test.txt file but the app is not started. When I start it manually with the exact same commands as are in RestartScript.sh, it starts without issues.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by changing the WantedBy section in appstart.service file to default.target.